# Is it ok to iterate backwards to one before the beginning of an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

If for example I have a ptr to a string and move ptr to last character in string and iterate backwards to beginning of string using *p-- and I iterate to position one before start of array is this OK?  Or will I get an access violation?  I am only moving pointer - not accessing.  It seems to work in my code so wondering if it is bad practice or not?

Here is a sample - line with *next-- = rem + 'A'; is one I am questioning if ok???

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* printf */
#include <string.h>    /* strlen, strcpy */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* malloc/free */
#include <math.h>      /* pow */

/* AAAAA (or whatever length) = 0, to ZZZZZ.  base 26 numbering system */
static void getNextString(const char* prev, char* next) {
   int count = 0;
   char tmpch = 0;

   int length = strlen(prev);
   int i = 0;
   while((tmpch = *prev++) != 0) {
      count += (tmpch - 'A') * (int)pow(26.0, length - i - 1);
      ++i;
   }

   /* assume all strings are uppercase eg AAAAA */
   ++count;

   /*if count above ZZZ... then reset to AAA... */
   if( count >= (int)pow(26.0, length))
      count = 0;

   next += (length-1);  /* seek to last char in string */
   while(i-- > 0) {
      int rem = count % 26;
      count /= 26;
      *next-- = rem + 'A';   /*pntr positioned on 1 before array on last iteration - is OK? */
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int buffsize = 5;
   char* buff = (char*)malloc(buffsize+1);

   strcpy(buff, "AAAAA");
   int iterations = 100;

   while(--iterations){
      getNextString(buff, buff);
      printf("iteration: %d buffer: %s\n", iterations, buff);
   }

   free(buff);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the following C-FAQ [question\answer](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/non0based.html), and I quote:

> Pointer arithmetic is defined only as long as the pointer points
>   within the same allocated block of memory, or to the imaginary
>   ``terminating'' element one past it; otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined, *even if the pointer is not dereferenced*.

So my answer would be **no**, it is not OK to iterate before the beginning of an array.

There are references to the C standards as well:

- K&R2 Sec. 5.3 p. 100, Sec. 5.4 pp. 102-3, Sec. A7.7 pp.
  205-6
- ISO Sec. 6.3.6 (C89) or 6.5.6/8 (C99)
- Rationale Sec. 3.2.2.3

Comment: +1: The [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) reference is to 6.5.6/8; the one you indicate must be for the C89 reference.

Comment: @pmg: Thanks! I added the C99 reference.

Comment: Does that mean that `for (char* tmp = s+len; tmp >= s; tmp--) *tmp = 'x';` is UB?

Comment: OK it looks like I need to re-design.

Comment: @ruslik: yes, it's UB ... and it's one write too many anyway. That code writes `'x'` at `s[len]`, which should be the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: @pmg: I was somehow aware what it does :)

Comment: @ruslik: I would say it is (assuming `s` if the beginning of an allocated block, and you don't know what is before it). If you absolutely need a backward loop, you could always write the not-so-pretty `for (char* tmp = s+len; tmp > s; ) *--tmp = 'x';`

Comment: In practice, however, it will work as expected an all common architectures and compilers.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't try to read or write from that address, it won't cause a violation.  This is becuase the value in a ptr is just another number.

Comment: I am confused now because all responses above are suggesting it is NOT ok.

Comment: The standard says that it's undefined behavior, although the typical C++ implementations should have no problems with it (on the other hand, modern optimizers are known to exploit every possible UB case to perform aggressive optimization, so you should be careful).

Comment: What Matteo says - it *is* undefined behavior, but pretty much any implementation you name will in fact do what you expect, which is to let you form (but not dereference) a one-before-the beginning pointer just as it lets you form (but not dereference) one-after-the-end.

Comment: They're ancient, but implementations for OS/2 1.x could cause exceptions just for trying to user a pointer to one before the beginning of an array without ever dereferencing it. They actually used the x86 segmentation; attempting to use a pointer like segment:offset where offset was less than the base value for that segment could result in a segment violation.

Comment: @user619818: They are saying that it is undefined, which is true, so theoretically it could do anything, including sending your mother a note saying that you're a bad programmer.  Practically speaking, the only problem might be the segmentation violation that Jerry mentions.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason your code is working is that your length happens to be less than or equal to the initial value in i.

I personally would not want to rely on this, since I know I'd forget about that particular condition, and I'd make some modification that broke it.  So while it technically works, it's not really a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

[expr.add], ¶5

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past
>   the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is
>    undefined.

So it's UB, since the result do not point to any valid element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

*comment, acctually: (to FelixCQ's answer)*

I could understand why obtaining an Out-of-range pointer in a loop could be dangerous because of possible loop unrolling and out-of-order evaluation, so that the pointer could get derefferenced before the terminating condition is evaluated, as in this simple example:

```
for (char* tmp = s+len; tmp >= s; tmp--) sum += *tmp;
```

However, if this is the reason for UB, then

```
for (int i = len; i >= 0; i--) sum += s[i];
```

has exactly the same problem! Or am I missing something?

Comment: No. The problem in the first loop is that `tmp` is equal to `s-1` after the loop. There is absolutely no problem with `i` being equal to `-1` after the second loop.